# adding a value with composition and partial application haskell

Tags: haskell, composition, partial-application

I'm trying to write this function applying composition and partial application with Haskell:

```
function m n = (m^2) + n
```

I tried this with:

```
function m = (m^2).(+)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the second one? What happens when you try it?

Comment: It was wrong. Please take a look at Willem's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with that approach is that `(+)` is a binary operator. Since you put it at the right of the dot `.`, it will not be applied to the left operand. So you have written:

```
function :: Num a => a -> a -> a
function m = (.) (m^2) (+)  -- wrong
```

This is short for:

```
function m = \n -> ((m^2) ((+) n))
```

So that means that `(+) n` will result in a function `(n+)` and we will apply that function to the result of `(m^2)`, which does not make much sense.

You can however simply use:

```
function :: Num a => a -> a -> a
function m = (+) (m^2)
```

Or:

```
function :: Num a => a -> a -> a
function m = ((m^2) +)
```

Given `function m = (+) (m^2)`, if we apply `n` on that function, we will obtain:

```
((+) (m^2)) n
-> (+) (m^2) n
-> (m^2) + n
```

You can further modify the `function` and drop the `m` argument as well, with:

```
function :: Num a => a -> a -> a
function = (+) . (^ 2)
```

Which is syntactical sugar for:

```
function :: Num a => a -> a -> a
function = (.) (+) (^2)
```

If we now apply `m` on the function, it will evaluate to:

```
((.) (+) (^2)) m
-> (\x -> (+) ((^2) x)) m
-> (+) ((^2) m)
-> (+) (m^2)
```

So we obtain the state like in the previous command.

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem